# Using Selenium with Chrome 87 and xvfb causing a crooked screen

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I'm using Fedora 30 to automate some Selenium testing.

I run Selenium on Chrome using xvfb (xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.20.5-4.fc30.x86_64).

I recently updated Chrome from version 76 to 87, and now the screen is crooked during every video test.

I have tried changing the screen size using the **maximize command**,

and **manually set the screen size**,

none of them solved *The crooked and skewed screen*.

Nothing has been changed on the system except The the Chrome update.

I am using java for the selenium code.

**Downgrading** obviously fixes the issue.

Has anyone ever had this issue before?

Was there some change made between **Chrome** or **Chromedriver** versions that I missed reading about?

Is there some setting or flag I'm missing with the new version of Chrome?

[Crooked Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NWtT.png)

Comment: A lot of text issues seem to be cleared up by disabling clearType.  Maybe try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. For some reason the new version of Chrome didn't like running in 16 bit color mode in XVFB.

I changed the color bit depth to 24 and the windows in the videos are showing correctly. Yay no more crooked screens!